# Using Views to add comments to user profiles

Tags: views, users, comments

My goal is to create an additional "ratings/comments" tab to user profiles in drupal 7 to allow authenticated users to leave comments/ratings for other users.  I've created a "ratings" content type (which naturally has comments enabled) and created a view around this type and added it as a user menu tab.

The problem is, since it is one content type, all the comments that have been left by any authenticated user show up on every single user's "ratings/comments" tab.  Of course I only want the comments that were meant for that particular user to show up.

Is this possible using filters?  I've been playing around with it but haven't been able to find the right setting just yet.  I know there is a guestbook module but I don't really want to go this route.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints which might push you in the right direction:

- Ratings can be handled with the [five star module](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar).
- I didn't test this, but the [profile 2 module](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) gives you the ability to tye a content type to a drupal user. Enabling comments for this content type could get you going.

Comment: Thanks.  I've already incorporated five star module for the ratings.  The comments are what is causing me some trouble.  I've been hearing about profile 2.. I suppose I may have to look into it.  But I was hoping for a way to use my current method while making use of view filters.  Doesn't seem like it's doable though